# Possible improper use of the word "should" in a word problem.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

The problem is taken from a high school textbook, section: Linear-Quadratic Systems: Adam jumps from a plane (he's skydiving). His height above the ground after he jumps and before he opens his parachute can be modelled by $h_1(t)=-4.9t^2+5500$, and his height after he pulls his parachute (until he hits the ground) can be modelled by $h_2(t)=-5t+4500$. According to these models, how long after jumping out of the plane *should* (emphasis added) Adam release his parachute.

My commentary and question is this: I personally find the use of the word "should" confusing here, because it makes it sound like Adam has some choice in the matter as to when he releases the parachute, which I don't think he does (correct me if I'm wrong). With optimization problems, it's common to see something like "What price should the business sell product X for to maximize profit?" This use of "should" makes sense to me, because there's freedom to vary price, and profit will change as a result.

But if Adam were really free to pull his parachute at different times, would it not be the case his height would instantaneously jump from one height to another (like a discontinuity), because at the instant he pulls his shoot, height changes from $h_1$ to $h_2$? So isn't it just the case that we need to equate the two values ($h_1$ and $h_2$) to see at what time they are equal (and thus no height discontinuity). Thus, wouldn't it be more correct to ask, "According to these models, when *does* (not should) Adam release his parachute?"

Any thoughts?

Comment: I totally agree, "should" doesn't make sens, and the only reasonnable thing you can do is to ask for $h$ to be continuous

Comment: @YannHamdaoui OK, great. Thanks for the validation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is badly worded in at least two ways.  I would suggest that "did" is a better word than "should".  As we are given the altitude as a function of time, there is a time when the chute was opened.  Also it uses $t$ in two different ways.  In the first, it is measured from jumping out of the airplane, while after opening the chute it is measured from the opening.  Some students will be tempted to assume the two $t$'s are the same.  In practice, we are expected to set the second $t$ to zero, finding that the altitude of opening the chute is $4500$, then to find the first $t$ that results in $h_1(t)=4500$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In regards to your analysis of the time variable, I'm not sure you're correct. I interpreted it as a piecewise function, with $h_1$ applying for $0\le t \le\text{Adam pulls the shoot}$ and $h_2$ applying for $\text{Adam pulls the shoot}\le t \le \text{Adam hits the ground}$. The answer provided in the book is that the cord is pulled at a height of 4426 m (not 4500 m), at a time of 14.8 s.

Comment: @yroc:  OK, I can see that.  It looked to me like they were resetting the zero, but it seems not.  In that case, I only see the problem you did.

Comment: OK, great. Your rep is so high that I would have continued to doubt myself had you not conceded! :-)